# Clonable File Input with Multiple Attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Having a bit of trouble with a clonable `<input tpye="files" multiple>` element, specifically handling the input on the PHP backend. Given the following form:

```
<form method="POST" action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="clonable">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]"/>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="attachments[][]" multiple/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note how the `title[]` is an array input, so multiple `titles` can be uploaded (following clone of `.clonable`), and the `attachments[][]` is multi-dimensional, as multiple files can be uploaded per `.clonable` div.

Here's a few scenarios:

**Single `.clonable` upload with 1 `attachment`**

```
// $request->input("title");
array:1 [▼
  0 => "Testing"
]

// $request->file("attachments");
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#27 ▶}
  ]
]
```

This is the correct upload structure; while I'm looping the input via

```
for($i = 0; $i < $clonableCount; $i++) {
```

I can access the title and attachments as

```
$title = $request->input("title.".$i); // "Testing"
$attachments = $request->file("attachments.".$i); // array(1)[0 => UploadedFile]
```

And everything is as it should be.

**Two `.clonable` uploads with 1 `attachment` each**

```
// $request->input("title");
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Testing"
  1 => "Testing 2"
]

// $request->file("attachments");
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#27 ▶}
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#28 ▶}
  ]
]
```

Again, everything is great, `0` and `1` of `$request->file("attachments")` are both arrays of a single `UploadedFile`, so the loop works.

**Single or Multiple `.clonable` with multiple `attachment`s each**

```
// $request->input("title");
array:1 [▼
  0 => "Testing"
]

// $request->file("attachments");
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▶]
  1 => array:1 [▶]
]
```

This is where things go wrong; `$request->file("attachments")` is an array of 2 `arrays`, each with 1 `UploadedFile`, so `$request->file("attachments.".$i);` will only return a single upload, even though there are multiple. This is compounded further with multiple `attachments` per `.clonable`:

```
// $request->input("title");
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Testing"
  1 => "Testing 2"
]

// $request->file("attachments");
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▶]
  1 => array:1 [▶]
  2 => array:1 [▶]
  3 => array:1 [▶]
]
```

Now `$request->file("attachments")` is an array of 4 `array`s, each with 1 `UploadedFile`, spread across 2 `.clonable`.

Long question, but basically, how do I handle something like this? I know I can add index names to the `attachment[][]`, like `attachment[0][]` and `attachment[1][]`, etc, so I'll do that if I have to, but I'm wondering if there's another, more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as expected, indexing the `attachments` is the best approach. Updated my clone function to include the following:

```
// Adjusted class to `class="form-control attachments"` on `input`
function reindexAttachments(){
    $(".attachments").each(function(index){
        $(this).attr("name", "attachments[" + index + "][]");
    });
}
```

And now upload of multiple `.clonable` with multiple `attachments` each results in:

```
// $request->input("title");
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Testing"
  1 => "Testing 2"
]

// $request->file("attachments");
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#27 ▶}
    1 => UploadedFile {#28 ▶}
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#29 ▶}
    1 => UploadedFile {#30 ▶}
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way. The only way I can say is like this:

```
<div class="clonable">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]"/>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="attachments[0][]" multiple/>
</div>
<div class="clonable">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]"/>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="attachments[1][]" multiple/>
</div>
```

You should set the `name` of each `input file` field when cloning.

Why? Just think about the PHP code like this:

```
$a = null;
$a[][] = 'x';
$a[][] = 'y';
$a[][] = 'z';
var_dump($a);
```

So you see:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(1) { [0] => x }
  [1] => array(1) { [0] => y }
  [2] => array(1) { [0] => z }
}
```

Comment: Yup. That's what I was afraid of. And yeah, good point on the PHP equivalent; makes total sense when you lay it out that way.